# Question about MIPS (million instructions per second) and CPI(Cycle per instruction)

Tags: statistics, arithmetic, computer-science, computational-complexity

I need help with the following problem

[image]

I understand the math behind every step, but I don't get the definitions. Why do we multiply the resultant CPI by 1 million. How does the dimensional analysis make sense?. It would be nice if you can provide a better explanation about CPI and MIPS. Although this question is related to engineering, I really think it's mostly related to math because we mostly take ratios and count.

Comment: What do you think the 'M' in 'MIPS' means?

Comment: $\text{MIPS} = { \text{IPS} \over 10^6} = {1 \over 10^6} { \text{CPS} \over \text{CPI}}$.

Comment: so it's the number in millions of instructions per second

Comment: That's what MIPS is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second#MIPS.